# Early Alzheimer's and cognitive remediation programs

Tags: memory, brain-training, brain-development

Early symptoms of Alzheimer’s disease (AD) includes the loss of short term memory including prospective memory.  On a physical level brain cells are being destroyed and that disrupts the neural pathways that form memory.

My interest is on cognitive remediation programs that use spaced repetition (spacing effect/spaced retrieval/gradual interval recall).   A Google scholar search
http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22spacing+effect%22+Alzheimer%27s&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_ylo=2000
lists many papers that show a positive effect but I don't know how to search for what is happening at a physical level?

Can someone describe the effect at the physical level?

In the book "The Foundations of Remembering: Essays in Honor of Henry L. Roediger, III" page 95:

> Camp and colleagues have argued that expanded retrieval training makes use of implicit memory, which is relatively spared even in the later stages of AD

What is implicit memory and why is it not affected by AD until late stages?

Comment: Where did you gather the initial information of your 'novice description'? In what way does or doesn't that source address the subsequent answers?

Comment: Steven,  thank you for you help with my question.  The "source" is myself based on bits that I've been exposed to via general media.  I am combining these bits into a hypothesis. This "source" is not a good place to go for the answers ;-)

Comment: As I get familiar with this site I am finding ways to locate material I was not aware of.  Another posting suggested searching google scholar.  This is resulting in some leads for me to follow.

Comment: Consider updating your question as you find new information to narrow it down.